In C, why ' ' and not " "?
Apologies in advance to the C masters out there. I'm very new to C and I'm working through an assignment in my course where I need to find words in a block of text.
Here I am trying to compare the character at index i of text.
if (text[i] == '.' && text[i+1] == " " && (isupper(text[i-1]) || islower(text[i-1])))
However, when i try to compile, I get this error.

error: result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified (use an explicit string comparison function instead) [-Werror,-Wstring-compare]

If I change the code to text[i+1] == ' ', then the code compiles. Why is this?

To clarify, text[i+1] == " " is comparing a character integer with a string literal (an array). It's also unclear why isupper(text[i-1]) || islower(text[i-1]) isn't the simpler isalpha(text[i-1]).

'x' is the integer value of the character x.  "x" is a pointer to a null-terminated string consisting of the character x (followed by a null character).

Thank you both for clarifying the difference! @WeatherVane Good suggestion with isalpha, I assumed there should be a function that checks for all alphabetical characters regardless of case, but I hadn't come across it quite yet.

Here is a list of the basic character classification functions FYI. isalpha, isdigit, isalnum, ispunct, isspace, isupper, islower, isxdigit, iscntrl, isprint, isgraph.
